# PySpark: Select a value from an Oracle table then add to it

Tags: python, oracle, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, amazon-emr

I load rows from Oracle to AWS using PySpark.
I grab 10000 rows at a time and then store the max seq_id loaded and use that for the next range.

I'm trying to do this in PySpark but I can't figure it out. Can anyone help or point me to a useful training resource please? I have tried casting the output as an Int. I tried select.collect[0][0] but get an error with it too. I'm very new to PySpark so any help is greatly appreciated.

```
from pyspark.conf import SparkConf
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

spark.conf.set("hive.exec.dynamic.partition", "true")
spark.conf.set("hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode", "nonstrict")
spark.conf.set("spark.sql.sources.partitionOverwriteMode","dynamic")

def oracle_read(user,pwd,hostname,port,service_name,table_name):
    url = 'jdbc:oracle:thin:'+user+'/'+pwd+'@//'+hostname+':'+port+'/'+service_name
    result = spark.read \
    .format("jdbc") \
    .option("url", url) \
    .option("dbtable",table_name) \
    .option("user", user) \
    .option("password", pwd) \
    .option("driver", "oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver") \
    .load() 
    result = result.toDF(* [c.lower() for c in result.columns])
    return result
    
max_seq_qry = """(SELECT max_val FROM data_owner.tbl_max_seq_load WHERE table_name = 'TBL_A')"""
max_seq = oracle_read(oracle_user,oracle_pass,oracle_host,oracle_port,oracle_service,max_seq_qry)
min_seq = max_seq + 1
max_seq = max_seq + 10000
```

I got the following errors:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'DataFrame' and 'int'
NameError: name 'IntegerType' is not defined
TypeError: 'instancemethod' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

Comment: whats the output of `print(max_seq.head())`?

Answer (score 1):

Your function `oracle_read` return a dataframe(result) and you are trying to increment it(add one to it), which is not possible and hence the error.

In your case, you are taking only one column 'max_val' from database and you probably the firt match, so you can select this column and take first value as `max_seq['max_val'].values[0]`

So you can rewrite your code as

```
max_seq = oracle_read(oracle_user,oracle_pass,oracle_host,oracle_port,oracle_service,max_seq_qry)
max_seq = int(max_seq['max_val'].values[0]) + 1
```

Comment: I got this error back when I tried that
TypeError: int() argument must be a string or a number, not 'Column'

Comment: did you do it with .values[0] as well?

Comment: Yep ```max_seq = int(max_seq['max_val'].values[0]) + 1``` I tried to split it up and get the value first and the convert but got ```TypeError: int() argument must be a string or a number, not 'Column' ```with either approach. Can I gather the results from the function into anything other than a dataframe? The particular sql will only ever bring back one value, I could create a new function that sends the result to an int or string

Comment: Can you please paste the exact line that produces error? Also whats the output of print(max_seq) after `oracle_read` line?

Comment: This is what the print shows ``` >>> print(max_txn_seq)
DataFrame[max_val: string] ```  This is the line and error I get ``` >>> min_seq = int(max_txn_seq['max_val'].values[0]) + 1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: int() argument must be a string or a number, not 'Column'
>>> ```

Answer (score 0):

can you please check if you have any rows where table_name = 'TBL_A', if there are no rows then try to add a NVL(max_val, 0 ) and see if that works.

Instead of storing the sequences in a Table, it is better to use Oracle sequence as it is more scalable and help in multiuser environment.

thanks